# Violation in deterministic skip-list topdown insertion

Tags: data-structures, skip-lists

Suppose I'm given a skip-list, with an order of 3.

```
           HEAD
level 3     |--------------------------------------------> X
            |                      |---|
level 2     | -------------------> |   | ----------------> X
            |    |---|    |---|    |---|    |---|
level 1     | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   | -> |   | -------> X
            |    |---|    |---|    |---|    |---|
            |    | 20|    |100|    |150|    |200|
            |    |---|    |---|    |---|    |---|


minlimit = ceil(order/2) - 1 = 1

maxlimit = order - 1 = 2
```

So essentially it's a `1-2 skip-list`.

If I want to insert `50` by the top-down insertion algorithm, it'll raise the level of node `100` before dropping into gap between `Head` and `150` and insert `50` right before `100`. Now a violation will occur as there are no nodes between `100` and `150` while there should be at least one node of height `h-1` in that gap as the `minlimit=1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: The code is doing exactly what I've stated above. I think the code is irrelevant since the question is about the algorithm, not it's implementation, I just want to know if the steps I'm doing in this particular scenario are correct or not. But if you think it is important, I can post it here.

Answer (score 2):

> If I want to insert 50 by the top-down insertion algorithm, it'll raise the level of node 100 before dropping into gap between Head and 150 and insert 50 right before 100

Why are you doing this?

The first reference I found for deterministic 1-2 skip lists ([this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=139478)), available ([PDF](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/skip-net-graph/deterministic-skip-lists-munro.pdf)) as per your link says:

> As noted in [...], insertions in ... can
>   be performed top-down, ... Adopting this
>   approach, we insert an element in a 1-2-3 skip list by
>   splitting any gap of size 3 into two gaps of size 1, when
>   searching for the element to be inserted. We ensure in
>   this way that the structure retains the gap invariant with or without the inserted element.
>
> To be more
>   precise, we start our search at the header, and at level
>   1 higher than the height of the skip list. When we find
>   the gap that we are going to drop, we look at the level
>   below and if we see 3 nodes of the same height in a row,
>   we raise the middle one; after that we drop down a level.
>   When we reach the bottom level, we simply insert a new
>   node of height 1.

According to this, you should start at level 3, and look at level 2 below. There are not 3 nodes of the same height in a row here - only the single node 150 - and so you don't need to raise anything. Now, drop down to level 2 in the gap [HEAD,150].

Does that start to address your confusion?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that it can be done in that way but the problem is that I have to get it done by using topdown insertion, in topdown insertion, as you go down, level of the middle node is increased if number of nodes at target level is equal to the 'maxlimit' as mentioned in [**this paper**](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/skip-net-graph/deterministic-skip-lists-munro.pdf). The purpose of doing it is to make insertion more efficient.

Comment: I do not understand that why this exception has occurred, since top-down insertion algorithm is well renowned and tested, it should work just fine. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You're confusing 1-2-3 skiplist with 1-2 skiplist. The one causing trouble is 1-2 skiplist, 1-2-3 works just fine by following the steps in paper. As you've mentioned that while dropping from level 3 to level 2 nothing needs to be done as there is only one node(150) at level 2 but while we are dropping in the gap [Head, 150] from level 2 to level 1, the middle node has to be raised because in 1-2 skiplist maxlimit is 2 (not 3 like 1-2-3 skiplist) and there are already 2 nodes in gap [Head, 150] so level of node 100 will be raised.

Answer (score 2):

> If I want to insert 50 by the top-down insertion algorithm, it'll raise the level of node 100 before dropping into gap between Head and 150 and insert 50 right before 100.

It would not raise the level of node 100. Rather it would raise the level of node 20. According to the algorithm, whenever you have the reached the `maxlimit` of nodes in a gap, you raise the level of the `ceil((maxlimit/2))th` node in that gap.

In this instance, when level of node 20 is raised to level 2, there is no level 1 node between  head and node 20 but it does not cause any structural violation. The original structure of deterministic skip lists as described in the paper by Munro et al. reads thus.

> Assuming that in a skip list of n elements there exists a 0th and a (n+1)st node of height 1 higher than the height of the skip list, we require that between any two nodes of height h (h > 1) or higher, there exist either 1 or 2 nodes of height h – 1.

Comment: Top down algorithm works for B-trees with both even and odd degrees, provide reference if you think you are right. In [**Munro's paper**](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/skip-net-graph/deterministic-skip-lists-munro.pdf) it is also stated that **"there exists
a one-to-one correspondence between 1-2 skip lists and
2-3 trees"** (the order in this case is 3, which is obviously odd and yet a correspondence exists) relevant examples are also given.

Comment: Please try to understand the statement and remain polite. SO does not encourage hostile attitude. 
The statement says between two nodes of height h; both the nodes would be at the same height h. If the two were different, it would have been at height h and h'.

Comment: I've found an answer to this, I'm not sure if it's correct either but there is a good chance. 1-2 skiplist is different from 1-2-3 skiplists just like 2-3 trees are different from B-trees and the same algorithm doesn't work with 1-2 skiplist, it has to be handled separately. I'm sorry to say that you are still confused with that statement but thank you for trying to help.